# I want to print crystal report on client machine,in c#

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports, report

This code is works successfully on server machine where the code is been installed, but when I am trying to print report from client machine its not going to work

Please help me sort out this problem.

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            string crptpath;
            crptpath = Server.MapPath("rpt_Water_FO_Gas_Consumption.rpt");
            doc.Load(crptpath);

            //For Local Server
            doc.SetDatabaseLogon("user_name", "password", "localhost", "ktem");

            //For Online Server
            //doc.SetDatabaseLogon("user_name", "password", "ip_address", "ktem");

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = dbcon.filldataset(cmd);

            doc.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dt.Tables[0]);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;

            //For Print Report
            CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode.Equals(true);
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Please specify the problem.

Comment: reports are loaded in both ways,
on server and client machine as well.

the problem is when i trying to print or export crystal report,
it works on server but not getting print on client machine and not showing any errors

Answer (score 0):

Check the path when you load the crptpath in client, if the path is correct verify that the server allows access to rpt.

Comment: reports are displayed in any ways

Comment: only print is not going to work when i clicked from client machine

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented has the answer:

```
     //For Local Server
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon("user_name", "password", "localhost", "ktem");
```

The database is running in the server. It works in the server. Got it? OK, in above code localhost represents server machine when the code is running is server. So report know where the database exits.

When you run the same code in client machine, the localhost represents the client machine and report complains that there is no database.

Replace local host with server ip address. [Taken from your commented piece of code]

```
        //For Online Server
        //doc.SetDatabaseLogon("user_name", "password", "12.121.114.220", "ktem");
```

Comment: no thats not my problem.the reports are generated by that code using server ip

Comment: the reports are generated in any condition thats not an issue.

but cant get printed when i click print option in that crystal report
from client machine.
and get printed When i clicked From server machine .
thats the actual problem